# Starting thread with member function

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I recently came across on such piece of code (here is simplified version, which I checked and it works):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Foo
        {
            public Foo()
            {
                thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Loop));
            }

            private void Loop()
            {
            }

            private Thread thread;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            Console.WriteLine("How does it work??");
        }
    }
}
```

Why does such code work without any complains from compiler? As I understand, Thread should start from function which should be static. (or reference to object and member function should be passed anyway). But here I see only passing reference to member function. It seems like I missed big thing in c#. May be there is implicit way of passing `this` reference?

**UPD:** great thanks. I just want to add minor addition of this fact. It turns out that compiler automatically handles delegates (passes correct reference object and method). here is il code:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ldarg.0
  IL_0009:  ldarg.0
  IL_000a:  ldftn      instance void Rextester.Program/Foo::Loop()
  IL_0010:  newobj     instance void 
[mscorlib]System.Threading.ThreadStart::.ctor(object,

native int)
  IL_0015:  newobj     instance void 
[mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread::.ctor(class 
[mscorlib]System.Threading.ThreadStart)
  IL_001a:  stfld      class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread 
Rextester.Program/Foo::thread
  IL_001f:  ret
} // end of method Foo::.ctor
```

Comment: *"should be static"* - wrong, it should only be static if created in static method. Try static constructor for this to be true. `Loop` as parameter is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) (means - compiler will take care to call it properly, e.g. using `this` if it's an instance member), it doesn't have to be static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But here I see only passing reference to member function.

The documentation says to the [ThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) that it is a delegate. It

> "represents the method that executes on a Thread.
>   When a managed thread is created, the method that executes on the thread is represented by a ThreadStart delegate"

---

> Thread should start from function which should be static.

This is not necessarily true. The function does not have to be static.

The documentation shows both examples. Using a static method and using an instance method:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        // To start a thread using a static thread procedure, use the
        // class name and method name when you create the ThreadStart
        // delegate. Beginning in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework,
        // it is not necessary to create a delegate explicitly. 
        // Specify the name of the method in the Thread constructor, 
        // and the compiler selects the correct delegate. For example:
        //
        // Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
        //
        ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork);
        Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        newThread.Start();

        // To start a thread using an instance method for the thread 
        // procedure, use the instance variable and method name when 
        // you create the ThreadStart delegate. Beginning in version
        // 2.0 of the .NET Framework, the explicit delegate is not
        // required.
        //
        Work w = new Work();
        w.Data = 42;
        threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(w.DoMoreWork);
        newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        newThread.Start();
    }
}

class Work 
{
    public static void DoWork() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure."); 
    }
    public int Data;
    public void DoMoreWork() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data={0}", Data); 
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In respect to the type delegate the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) says:

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type.

In this [tutorial on MSDN on deleagates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx) you can see how it can be instantiated using the `new` keyword:

> Instantiating a delegate   Once a delegate type has been declared, a delegate object must be created and associated with a particular method. Like all other objects, a new delegate object is created with a new expression.

That means that since `Loop` and `ThreadStart` have the same return type, namely `void` and the same parameter list, (here empty) you can instatiate the delegate using the name of the instance method `Loop`.

EDIT 2:

> I just was confused about using member function without reference.

This works because you declare the thread in the same class as where the method is declared.

> May be there is implicit way of passing `this` reference?

In this context, the answer is yes. If you call a method inside a class or use the name as delegate (pointer to the method) then the `this` is implicit.

Comment: Oh, great thanks. I missed that doc. I just was confused about using member function without reference.

Comment: @LmTinyToon you are welcome. Now I understand better your question "May be there is implicit way of passing this reference?" I edited my post and added the information. The answer is yes